# Make a browsable HDD copy under Windows

Tags: windows, disk-image

I need to clone a HDD and then be able to extract files from the image (it should be faster than copying files from that HDD).

This HDD can contain errors, so cloning software should be able to retry bad sectors.

There is [software](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) that allows mounting a raw HDD copy (although I haven't tested it), so I need to make a compatible image.

Comment: [This](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2421302,00.asp) might help.

Comment: What is "compatible image"? Do you need images in ISO format? Then [edit] that into your question.

Comment: I think [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com) will suit your needs.

Comment: You've linked to OSFmount in your question. The ReadMe file mentions [OSFclone](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/create-disk-images.html), which clones an HDD into an `iso` image that can be then mounted by OSFmount

Comment: @Timmy it is not for windows

Comment: @SmitJohnth True. It is a self booting tool, which you can load on a CD/DVD or USB from Windows. OSFmount will then mount the resulting image on WIndows without problems

Answer (score 2):

You *really* should be using linux for the initial backup since [gnuddrescue](https://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/) is probably the best choice for doing a full disk backup when there's bad sectors - it backs up good sectors first then retries the bad ones, letting you know which ones are bad. Once that's done, there's a few options for mounting it in windows - [osfmount](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/mount-disk-images.html) or [lmdisk](http://www.ltr-data.se/opencode.html/#ImDisk) might work. I'd rather mount the disk image in kpartx and copy it, personally.